# How can I debug an unrecognized selector sent to an NSNull object within a AppKit method

Tags: objective-c, xcode, debugging, selector

I have been receiving this exception in my debugger:

> -[NSNull _setWithOffsetDelta:]: unrecognized selector sent to
>   instance 0x7fff71d27210

Which okay sounds pretty easy to debug, so I set breakpoints on all Objective-C exceptions, and see that this exception is being thrown at this message:

```
  [textLayout drawGlyphsForGlyphRange:glyphRange atPoint:textBounds.origin];
```

Now this is where I'm lost, here's the top stack frames in the backtrace:

[image]

Also searching for "setWithOffsetDelta" or "withOffsetDelta" returns 0 results anywhere, so I have no idea what object was supposed to receive this message.

I figure if I can figure out which object was supposed to receive the message, I should be all set.

I have tried using the Variable View in Xcode debugger to find an object that is referencing `NSNull`, but can't see anything

Does anybody have anything I could try to figure this out?

Comment: is there any break point specific to objective-C or you just set all exception breakpoint ?

Comment: Specific to Objective-C, and that line I posted is indeed the line that is throwing the exception

Comment: what is inside of this method drawGlyphsForGlyphRange ?

Comment: I don't know, because it's a method in `NSLayoutManager`, an object provided by AppKit.  I don't believe I can view the source code anywhere?

Comment: did you look into glyphRange ? Are you sure it isnt out of range

Comment: Yup, it has location=0, length=13, which matches the length of the text

Comment: i forgot to ask, what is textlayout ? text bounds ?

Comment: Oh sorry, TextLayout is an NSLayoutManager and TextBounds is an NSRect that is the bounds of the text.  I actually think I found something-- the textLayout has an attribute for NSShadow that is NSNull.  I think this is the object that is supposed to be receiving the message.  We'll find out soon here

Answer (score 2):

Use an Objective-C breakpoint with action of "po $arg1".

[image]

Run the app to get the breakpoint and you will be at the line that causes the exception and the error message will be in the debugger console.

When you hit the exception breakpoint you may need to **click debug continue** a couple of times and you will get a backtrace and more error info.

Comment: I get the same error message :(  `-[NSNull _setWithOffsetDelta:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fff71d27210`  My problem is that I have no idea which object is supposed to be receiving that message, so I have no way of trying to figure out how to fix the issue

Comment: You may have to single step a couple of times to get to the line that caused the problem.

Comment: But I can't because the message is being sent within an AppKit method.  Unless there's a way I could view the source code for NSLayoutManager maybe?